# Efficient way to create JSON object from data.frame in R?

Tags: r, jsonlite

If we convert a `data.frame` into a JSON object, there appears to be a lot of repetition (of column names)

e.g.

```
library(jsonlite)
iris[1:4, ]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa


iris[1:4, ] %>% toJSON
[{"Sepal.Length":5.1,"Sepal.Width":3.5,"Petal.Length":1.4,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},{"Sepal.Length":4.9,"Sepal.Width":3,"Petal.Length":1.4,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},{"Sepal.Length":4.7,"Sepal.Width":3.2,"Petal.Length":1.3,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},{"Sepal.Length":4.6,"Sepal.Width":3.1,"Petal.Length":1.5,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"}] 

# Note the repetition of column names in the JSON object we created
```

This doesn't matter for small objects, but for some purposes this extra bloat will become troublesome.

Is there an easy and effective way to store the same information in JSON format more efficiently?

Comment: `rjson::toJSON` is much more compact

Comment: This depends what you mean by "the same information"? For example, `jsonlite::toJSON( iris[1:4, ] , dataframe = "columns" )` will give you a smaller object, but you'll lose the inherent relationship between key:value pairs.